# How to update an application deployed with gpo

Tags: group-policy, installation, windows-server-2022

I deployed VLC 3.0.18 using the software installation GPO, later i updated the package to 3.0.19 over the existing one without issues.

I now have to deploy 3.0.20, what's the correct procedure?

[gpo configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSORe.png)

Do i add a third package, updating one of them?
Do i delete the oldest one, and update the other?

[gpo update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxOuV.png)

Thank you.